# R Adding string to colnames if maximum value of each row is negative

Tags: r, string, if-statement, max

I want to add a column in my dataframe which contains the name of the column of absolute max of each row and add a - if the value is negative. I already know how to find the colname of the absolute max of each row:

```
Year$MAX <- names(Year)[max.col(abs(Year))]
```

All I want now is to add a - to those names, if the maximum value is negative.

```
structure(list(Year_PC1 = c(0.08894241, 0.0974053, 0.31973715, 
0.07872326, 0.11825688, 0.26693977, 0.38819524, 0.57135167), 
    Year_PC2 = c(0.00204647, -0.09659042, -0.28659028, -0.2004155, 
    -0.0087369, 0.09324472, 0.19295139, 0.28848406), Year_PC3 = c(-0.83007229, 
    -0.71032944, -0.54154965, -0.26636061, 0.51721381, 0.53136727, 
    0.3217693, 0.34030246), Year_PC4 = c(0.35526945, 0.42689586, 
    0.35262208, 0.41736156, 0.45505958, 0.38535098, 0.52572592, 
    0.40147004), Year_PC5 = c(-0.10552909, 0.05833399, -0.24412172, 
    -0.27525861, 0.26547298, 0.25128881, 0.22226087, 0.11638842
    ), Year_PC6 = c(0.00249045, -0.13485498, 0.03780119, 0.24958282, 
    -0.11141373, -0.02894633, -0.03219833, -0.09467442), Year_PC7 = c(0.02659417, 
    -0.02836294, 0.06889791, -0.39737906, -0.24853771, 0.28679878, 
    0.26115328, 0.18243498), Year_PC8 = c(-0.22630098, -0.03966049, 
    0.21745252, 0.29118665, 0.30205514, 0.14772134, 0.07806185, 
    0.05443241)), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not in a [tidy format](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/tidy-data.html#tidy-data-1), which means that every row should be one observation and every column should be one variable (in your example, every column is one observation and you have as many variables as rows). Using `tidyr`, we can tidy it up and see for each year which was the max absolute value and its sign. Joining the results on the initial (untidy) dataframe gives the desires result.

Note that I used a minimal example, which you should have in your question to avoid cluttering.

```r
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)

    Year <- tibble(Year_PC1 = c(-3, 2, 1),
                   Year_PC2 = c(1, 2, 3))

    Year <- Year %>% mutate(id = row_number())
    max_with_sign <- Year %>%
      pivot_longer(-id) %>%
      group_by(id) %>%
      summarize(
        col_sign = sign(value[which.max(abs(value))]),
        prefix = gsub("1", "", col_sign),
        MAX = paste0(prefix, name[which.max(abs(value))])
      ) %>%
      select(id, MAX)

    Year %>% left_join(max_with_sign, by = "id") %>% 
      select(-id)
    #> # A tibble: 3 x 3
    #>   Year_PC1 Year_PC2 MAX      
    #>      <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>    
    #> 1       -3        1 -Year_PC1
    #> 2        2        2 Year_PC1 
    #> 3        1        3 Year_PC2
```